# LetsEncrypt Challenge failed for domain when i try to get Certbot certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, challenge-response

I'm trying to get a SSL certificate. When I tried the `sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d example.com`  command it will give the following error.

```
http-01 challenge for "example.com"
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain ""
http-01 challenge for "example.com"
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 5.223.81.7: Invalid response from
   https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/TKQORWrjpM1hyx81XCC3DpzFYI_UDnWdr3U:
   404

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

When I looked at the logs at `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`. it gives the following log

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/client.py", line 374, in obtain_certificate
    orderr = self._get_order_and_authorizations(csr.data, self.config.allow_subset_of_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/client.py", line 421, in _get_order_and_authorizations
    authzr = self.auth_handler.handle_authorizations(orderr, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/auth_handler.py", line 91, in handle_authorizations
    self._poll_authorizations(authzrs, max_retries, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/_internal/auth_handler.py", line 180, in _poll_authorizations
    raise errors.AuthorizationError('Some challenges have failed.')
```

how could I get an SSL certificate with cerbot certonly?

Comment: Have you properly created the acme-challenge file thing?

Comment: Can you please provide me any document to create acme-challenge file?